# What is the meaning of robust framework( related to programming)?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, frameworks

What does it mean that a spring framework is robust framework ( I know it is good thing, but don't know the exact advantages) ? If it isn't that what kind of problem arises ?
2) How to know a framework is robust or not ?

Answer (score 1):

That is a very generic and broad question, but still, I will try to provide a short answer.

Spring is an almost 20 years old Framework that is wildly used in the Java world and thus it is battle-tested because so many people in so many different contexts are successfully using it. It is updated frequently with new versions adding features and improving others, usually following the tendencies of modern software development.

In short, I believe this is why you may hear someone saying that "Spring is robust framework".